# How to dynamically create Bash code with a loop and execute it as it is created

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I have a list of lines in a Bash script as follows

```
if [ ! -z "$clone01" ]; then git clone "$clone01"; fi
if [ ! -z "$clone02" ]; then git clone "$clone02"; fi
if [ ! -z "$clone03" ]; then git clone "$clone03"; fi
#      $clone01 .... through to ...  $clone60
if [ ! -z "$clone60" ]; then git clone "$clone60"; fi
```

the leading zero at the end of the variable, when the number is less than 10, is important.

I have tried various substitutions and loops etc.
This code is very repetitive, and there are 60 lines of it.

How can I create this code dynamically and make it part of my executed script? What is the optimal approach to this problem?

Comment: Do you have sixty variables named `clone01` to `clone60`?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes I do. I have numbers 1 all the way through to 60

Comment: @Kes That's exactly what we were afraid to hear.

Comment: @dr01 Thanks. This is all part of automating IDE Arduino install. In the past I often found I had to customise my old install for a specific library arrangement. Then, after a few months, I would return to Arduino IDE and couldn't then remember why the install was broken for a different sketch/ library set-up. I will now store specific Arduino set-up's as a bash script.  It's going to save an awful lot of bother and re-discovery. Then I will not need so many libraries. I think ilkkachu has suggested below how the loop will only suck up as many libraries as there are. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, don't do that, it's ugly. Either put the URLs in an array and loop over it:

```
urls=( http://this.git http://that.git )
for url in "${urls[@]}" ; do
    git clone "$url"
done
```

or put them in a file, one per line, and loop reading the lines. Here, it might be useful to guard for empty lines, just like you did. We could also ignore lines starting with `#` as comments:

```
while read -r url ; do
    if [ -z "$url" ] || [ "${url:0:1}" = "#" ]; then continue; fi
    git clone "$url"
done < file.with.urls
```

If you want the line counter too, it's easy to add with [arithmetic expansions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Arithmetic_Evaluation).

Comment: Thanks @Ilkkachu this answer solves the problem, indeed it took my paradigm a step further, and I can use numbers, below, up until, or larger than 60. It also allows me to store the url's in a neat array, introduce `#` comments above each url and skip the blanks between entries. A very neat solution and the solution I used.

Comment: @Kes, good! (plus a filler)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `eval` to do this. Much better tool is [variable indirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection):

```
for i in clone{01..60}; do 
   [[ ${!i} ]] && git clone "${!i}"
done
```

`[[ $var ]]` does the same as `[ ! -z "$var" ]`. Note that storing 60 values in 60 variables is not the best approach and you might want to use arrays to do this.

Comment: as mentionned in my deleted answer, I learn a new bash trick today.

Comment: @Archemar don't forget that `eval` is common misspelling of `evil` and in most cases variable indirection or namerefs (with `bash` 4.3 or later) are better options ;)

Comment: @PesaThe this answer solves the problem. Thank you. Ilkkachu's answer below is the one I used it took my paradigm a step further.

Comment: @Kes ilkkachu's answer uses arrays and is therefore really the better approach you should use ;) I merely introduced a way to make your code work as it is, with 60 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your if in a for loop like this one?

```
for i in clone{01..60}; do echo $i; done
```

This results in the following output:

```
clone01
clone02
clone03
... clipped for length ...
clone60
```

So something like this seems like it will do the trick:

```
for i in clone{01..60}; do if [ ! -z $i ]; then git clone $i; fi; done
```

Helpful resources for this:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html

Comment: this will evaluate to **string** clone01 not value of $clone01.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin-Nelson. I made a small modification to your helpful code, just after `git clone` as follows and now it works. Here you code I have working `for i in clone{01..60}; do if [ ! -z $i ]; then git clone "${!i}"; fi; done`

Comment: @Kes even though it seems correct, you really need to use indirection even inside `[ ]`, just like it is in my answer. Only `[ ! -z $i ]` will always be true.